# initializationError FAILED java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, securityexception

I'm suddenly starting to get this error when the unit-test are running:

```
com.mycompany.myfeature.InputTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.SecurityException
```

I have no idea even where to start checking it. Any ideas?

Some info on my env that might help:

Java 8
Gradle 2.0
New packages that were added lately: Consul, Jetty and Jersy

Answer (score 2):

Check your `build/reports/tests/test/index.html` and then check the failing test.

I have seen this before when you have a test in an invalid package (i.e. mistakenly having `package java.net.something` or another invalid package name).

The HTML reports should have the specific information in them.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error . If the package name is like java.lib , then it throws a security exception , tested the plugin by changing the source code package name to my.lib and it worked